# Is more there efficient way to add different colors to RecyclerView text?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Whilst this method works and gets the job done, I feel there must be a more efficient way of doing this. I've tried to make an array containing the colors and add them using a for loop, but have failed to get it working... Any advice would be much appreciated.  Please see code below. Thanks

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LineViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.lineName.setText(lineList.get(position).getLineName());
        holder.lineStatus.setText(lineList.get(position).getLineStatus());


        if(position==0)
            holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        else if(position==1)
            holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        else if(position==2)
            holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        else if(position==3)
            holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        else if(position==4)
            holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        else if(position==5)
            holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        else if(position==6)
            holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        else if(position==7)
            holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        else if(position==8)
            holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        else if(position==9)
            holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        else if(position==10)
            holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        else if(position==11)
            holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        else if(position==12)
            holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        else if(position==13)
            holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);


    }
```

Comment: Set up a `static` 14-position `Color[]` array, where you assign values for each position. Reference that `Color[]` array to get the `Color` for a `position` in `onBindViewHolder()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.add color to `Integer[]` array

2.use `holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(colors[position]);` in your code

Try like this .

```
Integer[] colors = {Color.RED,Color.BLUE,Color.GREEN};
holder.lineName.setBackgroundColor(colors[position]);
```